# Google Apps Script ----> Convert numberLong to date format (e.g. 2015-12-02T16:51:31+00:00)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm new to google app script. I'm using Mongodb/Realm-Services. How do I convert numberLong digits(e.g. 1436815400277) to be in date format(e.g. 2015-12-02T16:51:31+00:00)? Thanks. Still researching will post if I figure it out first.

```js
function importMongoDBData() {

  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const getData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://....').getContentText()
  const jsonObj = JSON.parse(getData)
  for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
     sheet1.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(jsonObj[i].createdAt.$date.$numberLong)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) you will be able to adjust your date to whichever date format and time zone you want. Also, just by inserting the number of milliseconds into the Javascript [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor, it will automatically convert it to be used by `Utilities.formatDate()` as described in the linked documentation.

> A JavaScript date is fundamentally specified as the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since midnight on January 1, 1970, UTC.

```js
function importMongoDBData() {
  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const getData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://....').getContentText()
  const jsonObj = JSON.parse(getData)
  for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
     sheet1.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(jsonObj[i].createdAt.$date.$numberLong), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see it looks like that the numberLong is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, so I am going to base my answer on that.

In javascript, if you end up using the function `new date(input_number);` you should get a formatted date off of your input.

So with that, it looks like your code would look like:

```
function importMongoDBData() {

  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const getData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://....').getContentText()
  const jsonObj = JSON.parse(getData)
  for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
     sheet1.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(new date(jsonObj[i].createdAt.$date.$numberLong))
  }
}
```

Comment: You will get a date but I don't think it will be formatted. toISOString() is pretty close to what they want I think.  But if that doesn't work you could always use Utilities.formatDate()